# How to find the max value in an array, including numbers

Tags: java, arrays, input

I have to be able to find the maximum negative value within a 5 long array, whether the array contains negative or positive integers. I know this is simple, but if you lead me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

```
//Import Scanner so we can receive input from the user.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mess {

   //Main Method
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Declare variables
      int [] list = new int [6];
      int num = 0;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      int max = 0;

      //While loop to store in array
      while (num<=5){
      list [num]=input.nextInt();
      num++;
   }

   //Arrays.sort(list);
   //For loop to find max value
   //list[num]= max;
   System.out.print(max);System.out.print(max);
   for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
      if (list[i] > max){
         max = list[i];
      }
   }      
   //Print out max value
   System.out.print("The max value is " + max + " ");
   input.close();   
   }
}
```

Comment: so what is wrong?

Comment: Oh I see, start your second loop at `0`

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)` don't start at 1 but at 0 ;)

Comment: The loop returns 0 if a negative number is the highest number.

Comment: And aren't you actually looking for the minimum value ( ie the largest negative value )?

Comment: initially set max to Integer.MIN_VALUE;

Comment: Note : use list.length instead `while (num<=list.length){` and `for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initially set max to  Integer.MIN_VALUE

```
      //Declare variables
    int [] list = new int [6];
    int num = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    //While loop to store in array
    while (num<=5){
        list [num]=input.nextInt();
        num++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (list[i] > max){
           max = list[i];
        }
     }

    //Print out max value
    System.out.print("The max value is " + max + " ");
    input.close();
```

Comment: I appreciate it! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting with a `max` of zero so if the array contains all negative values none of them will trigger the `if` statement and `max` won't be overwritten.

```
max = list[0];
 for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        if (list[i] > max){
           max = list[i];
        }
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate it. It has been a long day. I guess I have been staring at my monitor too long.